# Convert UTF <U+something> to nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this strange storage of UTF string:

```
<U+0410><U+043B><U+044C><U+043A><U+0430>
```

How can I convert it back to nvarchar? The string above should be converted to `Алька`

Update. Here is more sample data:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|                                   Column1_encoded                                   | Column1_decoded |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| <U+0410><U+043B><U+044C><U+043A><U+0430>                                            | Алька           |
| ABC <U+0410><U+043B><U+044C><U+043A><U+0430> 1                                      | ABC Алька 1     |
| <U+0410><U+043B> 2 <U+044C><U+043A><U+0430>                                         | Ал 2 ька        |
| <U+0410><U+043B><U+044C><U+043A><U+0430> 3 <U+0410><U+043B><U+044C><U+043A><U+0430> | Алька 3 Алька   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

I got this strange format while sending data from Power BI to SQL Server via R transform exactly this way:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51386029/1903793

The answer of Jeroen Mostert in comment seem to handle it. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please give a few examples of the string you have stored and what you want them to be converted to?

Comment: @iamdave I have updated my question.

Comment: Are you sure that's what's literally in the string (as in, `LEFT(s, 1) = '<'`) and it's not some funky way that client tooling is displaying Unicode characters? Just to make sure you're not wasting your time on an unnecessary conversion.

Comment: It's hard to do this reliably in T-SQL in a way that's also fast. You can bounce through XML for a conversion (`SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(XML, REPLACE(REPLACE('<U+0410><U+043B><U+044C><U+043A><U+0430>', '<U+', '&#x'), '>', ';')))`) but this fails dramatically if your string has `>` characters unrelated to this scheme, and I'd be uncomfortable promoting that as a general solution. A more reliable replacement needs string matching features that T-SQL doesn't have, though.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, it worked. Of course there are such characters, like numbers. It seems that only exotic charters where transformed to `<U+something>`

Comment: So you're saying that these characters are appearing randomly within other strings?  You should really have added this context to your question as this completely changes the required solution.

Comment: Yes, numbers will be left alone -- but a string like `<hello>` will fail because the result ends up as invalid XML, so any string that has `<` or `>` outside the context of these `<U+` tags could fail. Incidentally, I think neither R nor ODBC nor PowerBI actually format Unicode characters this way, so that doesn't really clear up where these strings come from (although I have no experience with that particular setup). I'd expect your source data to already contain it.

Comment: You are right. I was lucky. When I run your query on larger table it flipped with error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use this across multiple column values you will need to convert it to a table valued function and call it via `cross apply`, though I am sure you can manage that yourself.  Explanation is in the comments:

```
declare @str nvarchar(1000) = '<U+0410><U+043B><U+044C><U+043A><U+0430> This is a string with <U+0410><U+043B><U+044C><U+043A><U+0430> not encoded as we would like <U+0410><U+043B><U+044C><U+043A><U+0430>';

-- Add an additional > character before the first < character to act as the first delimiter
-- and then insert a delimiting > character before any instances of a < chracter that follow a space to ensure the character code is properly parsed out.
select @str = replace(stuff(@str,charindex('<',@str,1),0,'>'),' <',' ><');

                -- Start tally table with 10 rows.
with n(n)   as (select n from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n(n))
                -- Select the same number of rows as characters in @str as incremental row numbers.
                -- Cross joins increase exponentially to a max possible 10,000 rows to cover largest @str length.
    ,t(t)   as (select top (select len(@str) a) row_number() over (order by (select null)) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4)
                -- Return the position of every value that follows the specified delimiter.
    ,s(s)   as (select 1 union all select t+1 from t where substring(@str,t,1) = '>')
                -- Return the start and length of every value, to use in the SUBSTRING function.
                -- ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the last value where there is no delimiter at the end of the string.
    ,l(s,l) as (select s,isnull(nullif(charindex('>',@str,s),0)-s,4000) from s)
    ,r      as (select rn as ItemNumber
                    ,Item
                from(select row_number() over(order by s) as rn
                            ,substring(@str,s,l) as item
                    from l
                    ) a
                where Item <> ''
                )
select cast((select case when left(Item,3) = '<U+'  -- Where required, convert the Unicode number into a character using the NCHAR function
                        then nchar(convert(nvarchar(500),convert(int,(convert(varbinary(max),replace(Item,'<U+','0x0000'),1)))))
                        else Item
                        end
            from r
            order by ItemNumber
            for xml path('')
            ) as nvarchar(max)) as String;
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| String                                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Алька This is a string with Алька not encoded as we would like Алька |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, I know what TVF is. Great help.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin  If this was the correct solution for your question as posted, for the benefit of other SO users, please mark it as the correct answer