# Unpivot file with power query results in file with more than 1 million records

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, unpivot

Is there any chance to get a file splitted before the unpivoting process is completed? I have tried to do the opposite, that is to split the file and then unpivot it, but it requires too much time due to the fact I have to deal with more than 20 files and I can't be able to write a functioning Macro to do the job.
I have to materialise it because I have to load the files into another software that does not have the unpivoting function in it and I can't get direct access to their databases to run any queries.

Comment: Power Query can easily cope with more than a million records. The question would be why you are materialising the output... I can't imagine a good reason. But it would be trivial to have a query to unpivot the data, then two (or more) queries to filter (split) the results of the first query, into batches of the required row count. Please [edit] your question to provide the required clarity.

Comment: If your software accepts CSV files you should be able to use [DAX Studio](https://daxstudio.org/) to create a CSV file directly from your data model (in DAX Studio click on the *Output* button in the ribbon and change it to *File* before running the query).

Comment: Hi Hsan, thank you for your reply but I can't install any software on my devices being the data GDPR sensitive and therefore I have to use my Office ones. I have Power BI though, may I do the trick with it?

Comment: I don't think PowerBI has a way to directly export the data model. However, you can create a visual (table or chart should both work) with all the columns you are interested in, then click on the `...` to open its menu and click on *Export data" to create a CSV.

Comment: I have imported the Power Pivot data model with all the databases successfully unpivoted, but for some reason, it does not show any of the data. All combined I have almost 9 millions rows. could be this the reason?

Comment: 9 million rows shouldn't be a problem for PowerBI. However, I just found out that an export limit was introduced with the November update limiting CSV exports to 30,000 rows... which makes this functionality useless anyways. Looks like there are workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51386029/2007837

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possible solution using VBA. In this approach you need to:

1. Load the Power Query table into Power Pivot Workbook Data Model
2. Fetch data from the Workbook Data Model using VBA
3. Write the records into a CSV file

Below is step by step how to.

For proofing, I created a dummy table of 3 million rows inside Power Query using below code, naming it "MyData".

```
// MyData: A table of 3 million rows

let RowCount = 3000000
in Table.FirstN(
    Table.FromColumns({
        List.Generate(() => 1, each true, each _ + 1),
        List.Generate(() => Number.Random() * 1000, each true, each Number.Random() * 1000)
    }, type table [ID = Int64.Type, RandomNumber = number]),
    RowCount
)
```

[image: MyData]

I loaded this table into the Workbook Data Model by selecting **Close & Load To**, then selecting **Only Create Connection** and checking **Add this data to the Data Model**.

Then, using below VBA code, I was able to connect to the Data Model, fetch the records, and dump it to a CSV file.

```vb
Const OutFile As String = "C:/path/to/MyData.csv"

Dim Wb As Workbook
Set Wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Wb.Model.Initialize

'Connection to the Data Model
Dim Conn As Object 'ADODB.Connection
Set Conn = Wb.Model.DataModelConnection.ModelConnection.ADOConnection

Dim Recordset As Object 'ADODB.Recordset
Set Recordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Dim Query As String
Query = "EVALUATE MyData" 'DAX query to return the entire table

Recordset.Open Query, Conn

Dim FileNum: FileNum = FreeFile()
Open OutFile For Output As #FileNum

Do While Not Recordset.EOF
    Write #FileNum, Recordset("MyData[ID]"), Recordset("MyData[RandomNumber]")
    Recordset.MoveNext
Loop

Close #FileNum
```